Headless argument still shows the browser as a blank white page instead of hiding it. I’m using Selenium in Python
I’m using headless browsing in Selenium. Normally, it hides the browser, but after restarting my laptop, it won’t hide it anymore. It is now displayed as a blank white page, which is not interactable. My guess is that maybe ChromeDriver or Chrome updated when restarting the OS, and perhaps the versions no longer match up. e.g
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)

driver.quit()

Updating or downgrading Chrome/ChromeDriver won’t solve the issue. Using --headless or --headless=new doesn’t work as intended. It hides the content of the page, making it a blank page, but the browser is still visible.

thanks,
--headless=old fixed it for me

--headless=new &  options.add_argument("--window-position=-3000,-3000")
also helps
